# Simplify expressions with Log

Tags: simplifying-expressions

How can I get *Mathematica* to simplify the following expression

```
n Log[a] + m Log[b] - m Log[a + b] - n Log[a + b]
```

into

```
Log[ a^n b^m (a + b)^(-m - n)] ?
```

I've tried various methods without any luck including: -

```
FullSimplify[ n Log[a] + m Log[b] - m Log[a + b] - n Log[a + b], { a + b > 0 } ]
```

Perhaps I'm not including enough assumptions or *Mathematica* doesn't consider this to be a simplification ? It would be nice to have a solution that doesn't require pattern matching.

Comment: In general Log[a^n] does not equal n*Log[a]. Take for instance Log[(-1)^2]. However, MMA knows that `Assuming[{n > 0, m > 0, a > 0, b > 0},  FullSimplify[n Log[a] + m Log[b] == Log[a^n b^m]]]` is True. So, these assumptions should be sufficient, but I cannot let it make the simplification itself.

Comment: This [Q&A](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/22333/4330) seems to be a bit overlooked. The OP there wants to do things **the other way around**, i.e. go from a Log of a product to the sum of Logs. It is a subjective matter what a simplification is, so I like Artes answer here below. The OP in the link uses something similar. The answer in the link by wolfies  just points to proprietary software, but can possibly provide some (professional) context. The answer in the link by Andre also seems great.

Comment: Only for completeness: You can perform the reverse operation (expanding the Log[] function) via `PowerExpand[]`.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Let us introduce the function to transform the logarithm:

```
    collectLog[expr_] := Module[{rule1, rule2, a, b, x},
   rule1 = Log[a_] + Log[b_] -> Log[a*b];
   rule2 = x_*Log[a_] -> Log[a^x];
   (expr /. rule1) /. rule2 /. rule1 /. rule2
   ];
```

This is your expression:

```
expr = (n Log[a] + m Log[b] - m Log[a + b] - n Log[a + b]);
```

Let us first simplify it, and then apply to it the collectLog function:

```
    expr2 = Simplify[expr, {a > 0, b > 0}, 
   TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, ComplexExpand}] // 
  collectLog
```

The result is

`Log[a^n b^m] + Log[(a + b)^(-m - n)]`

Let us apply the collectLog once more:

```
expr2 // collectLog
```

The result is:

```
Log[a^n b^m (a + b)^(-m - n)]
```

Done.

To answer the recent question of bszd: if a function with multiple Logs may be designed.

It can be done in a more simple way. If one has a lengthily expression with logarithms of the sort that might be simplified by collection, the function Nest may do the job:

```
 Nest[collectLog, expr, Length[expr]]
```

The answer is:

```
Log[a^n b^m (a + b)^(-m - n)]
```

If it is only a part of expression that, however, contains multiple logarithms to be collected, the function

```
collectAllLog[expr_] := Nest[collectLog, expr, Length[expr]];
```

may be mapped onto this part.

Finally, to complete this one may need to do the opposite operation: to expand the logarithmic expression. One way to do this would be to use the following function:

```
    expandLog[expr_] := Module[{rule1, rule2, a, b, x},
   rule1 = Log[a_*b_] -> Log[a] + Log[b];
   rule2 = Log[a_^x_] -> x*Log[a];
   (expr /. rule1) /. rule2
   ];
```

and

```
expandAllLog[expr_] := Nest[expandLog, expr, Depth[expr]]
```

For example,

```
expandAllLog[Log[a^n b^m (a + b)^(-m - n)]]
```

yields

```
n Log[a] + m Log[b] + (-m - n) Log[a + b]
```

as expected.

Comment: This looks very good. Is there any easy way I can allow multiple arguments for rule1, i.e. `rule1 = Log[a_] + Log[b_] + Log[]... -> Log[a*b*...]`?

Comment: @bsdz, Please have a look at the part I added to the answer.

Comment: Perfect - that's exactly what I was looking for with the added benefit it can be applied in other situations too. Thanks!

Comment: I am wondering how can I do the same replacement rules with functions sitting in front ? $e^{-i x}\log(a) + e^{ -i x} \log(b) \rightarrow e^{-i x}\log(a*b)$

Comment: @ Jaswin There are several ways. 1) You may introduce a rule: `rule = u_*Log[v_] + u_*Log[w_] :> u*Log[v*w]` and apply it to your expression; `expr = E^(-I*x)*Log[a] + E^(-I*x)*Log[b]` as follows: `expr /. rule`. 2) Otherwise, you may first factor the expression and then apply to its part the `collectLog` function: `MapAt[collectLog, expr // Factor, 2]`.

Comment: I tried the first method, it fails when $e^{-ix} \log(a) - e^{-i x} \log(b)\rightarrow e^{-i x} \log(a/b)$. Actually I have lot of these functions in my expression, and I want to replace everywhere to simplify.

Comment: @ Jaswin You have to create a rule such that it covers all cases that you can meet. This is not difficult.

Comment: OK will do that

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch : I made two rules -  rule1 = u_*Log[v_] + u_*Log[w_] :> 
  u*Log[v*w]; rule2 = -u_*Log[v_] + u_*Log[w_] :> u*Log[w/v]; it is not working for some reason, am I missing something trivial ?

Comment: @Jaswin Let `expr = E^(-I*x)*Log[a] - E^(-I*x)*Log[b]`. Try this: `rule = {Log[u_] - Log[v_] :> Log[u/v], -Log[u_] + Log[v_] :> Log[v/u]}` and then `MapAt[ReplaceAll[rule], expr // Factor, 2]`.

Comment: Actually it works in simple case but in a complicated expression this fails. I have lot of logs with different u's and V's but same prefactor function.

Comment: In fact I have asked a separate question with typical expressions i encounter.

Comment: @Jaswin 1. In general, logarithms are a difficult place in Mma. It never simplifies expressions containing them. I do not know the reason. Maybe, because it is not really clear, what expression the user will consider being better, with collected or with expanded logarithms. For this reason, it is typically impossible to automatically simplify all parts of the expression containing the logarithms, especially if there are plenty of such. One has to invent suitable approaches.

Comment: @Jaswin 2. Solutions I proposed always work for me, but they sometimes require slight modifications depending on the form of the expression in question. To do this, one needs to understand the code. Are you sure that you understand it?

Comment: @Jasmin 3. The solution of your problem cannot work this way. Please formulate your problem as a separate question and give your example that will include all typical subexpressions you have there. Probably it will enable one to find a more general function suitable for all your subexpressions.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch : I had asked a separate question, and it was answered satisfactorily. Yes I realised at times one needs to expand or collect and simplify or refine to get things done. I understand little coding in mathematica, the basic functions. Alteast now I am managing to do some simplifications.

Answer (score 21):

I know, I know: Now someone will ask why. Anyway:

```
FullSimplify@Log@Exp[n Log[a] + m Log[b] - m Log[a + b] - n Log[a + b]]

(* Log[a^n b^m (a + b)^(-m - n)] *)
```

Comment: Short and sweet. I mean that. Not like when my HS track coach would say it (which roughly translated to "I'm trying to make you puke this afternoon").

Comment: That's great. Shall test it tomorrow. Thank you

Comment: `Simplify` works, too (in place of `FullSimplify`).

Comment: Why does this work? :^)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard - it works because it's shorthand for `Simplify[Log[Exp[n Log[a] + m Log[b] - m Log[a + b] - n Log[a + b]]]]` . So works perfectly for this expression; however, it won't work for more complex expressions. See the [Prefix](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Prefix.html).

Comment: @bsdz It was a joke ...

Comment: @belisarius It is exactly the place, where science transforms itself into the art. Excellent.

Comment: It is interesting!

Answer (score 10):

Well, although late, here's an answer using `ReplaceRepeated (//.)`.

Let's define two replacement rules to take us back and forth.

```
logrule = {Log[x_] + Log[y_] :> Log[x y], n_ Log[x_] :> Log[x^n]}

revlogrule = {Log[x_ y_] :> Log[x] + Log[y], Log[x_^n_] :> n Log[x]}
```

Now here's your problem

```
expr = n Log[a] + m Log[b] - m Log[a + b] - n Log[a + b]
```

using the `logrule` we can simplify your expression:

```
expr //. logrule
```

Which gives:

> `Log[a^n b^m (a + b)^(-m - n)]`

Now let's go back to the original expression using `revlogrule`

```
Log[a^n b^m (a + b)^(-m - n)] //. revlogrule // Expand
```

> `n Log[a] + m Log[b] - m Log[a + b] - n Log[a + b]`

**EDIT**

You can also use `FullSimplify` with `TransformationFunctions` as follows. First define the transformation you desire to be applied:

```
tfunc[x_] := x /. logrule
```

Then:

```
FullSimplify[expr, TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, tfunc}]
```

Which gives as before:

> `Log[a^n b^m (a + b)^(-m - n)]`

Comment: I don't believe you need the rule `Log[x_] - Log[y_] :> Log[x/y]` as I think this should be handled by `Log[x_] + Log[y_] :> Log[x y]`.  Likewise `Log[x_/y_] :> Log[x] - Log[y]`.  There can be [surprises](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18993/121) but I don't think that particular case applies here. (+1)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, Ah yes, fixed. Thanks.

Comment: By the way, if [this account](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5695/runnykine) is yours you might [request a merge.](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard. Thanks a lot!. I've been looking for a way to do that.

Answer (score 1):

How about this one.

```
logList = n Log[a] + m Log[b] - m Log[a + b] - n m Log[a + b] 
         - n Log[a + b] - Log[ArcSin[a + b n]] + z Log[z];

mahmoh = Log[Times @@ (logList /. Times[x___, Log[y___]] :>
            Power[y,Times[x]] /. Log[x__] :> Power[x, 1])]

Out[376]=Log[(a^n b^m (a + b)^(-m - n - m n) z^z)/ArcSin[a + b n]]
```

All is fine as long as you dont use products of `Log` and here is a little Test

```
logList /. {a -> 2.3, b -> 4.3, n -> .4, m -> .7, z -> 3}
Out[377]= 1.09137 + 0.921334 I
mahmoh /. {a -> 2.3, b -> 4.3, n -> .4, m -> .7, z -> 3}
Out[378]= 1.09137 + 0.921334 I
```

The same answer at least.

And using the nice package MaTeX you get this little nice picture.

```
MaTeX[mahmoh, Magnification -> GoldenRatio]
```

[image]

I did not give it a very carefull thought so maybe you can find situation when it will not work. any suggestion would be more than welcome.

As for the original question the answer is

```
Log[a^n b^m (a + b)^(-m - n)]
```

[image]