# How to convert this answer into $\ln$ form?

Tags: output-formatting

I find the integral

```
Integrate[Sqrt[2 x - x^2] + x^3 Log[(9 - x^2)/(9 + x^2)], {x, 0, 2}]
```

and got

```
1/2 (-36 + π + 65 ArcTanh[4/9])
```

How can I write this answer has the form $\dfrac{65}{4} \ln \dfrac{13}{5} + \dfrac{\pi}{2}-18$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
expr = 1/2 (-36 + \[Pi] + 65 ArcTanh[4/9]) // TrigToExp

(*   -18 + \[Pi]/2 + 65/4 Log[13/9] + 65/4 Log[9/5]   *)


MapAt[HoldForm, expr, {{1}, {2}}] // Simplify // ReleaseHold

(*   -18 + \[Pi]/2 + 65/4 Log[13/5]   *)
```

Answer (score 5):

A little more general approach:

```
expr = 1/2 (-36 + \[Pi] + 65 ArcTanh[4/9])

expr /. x : ArcTanh[_] :> Simplify[TrigToExp[x]]
```

> ```
> 1/2 (-36 + \[Pi] + 65/2 Log[13/5])
> ```

About simplifying expressions with `Log` take a look [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/22705/5478) too.