# Collecting the Log Problem

Tags: core-language, algebraic-manipulation

I have been having tremendous success with my students due to the following idea:

```
expandLog = {Log[x_] + Log[y_] :> Log[x y], n_ Log[x_] :> Log[x^n]}

collectLog = {Log[x_ y_] :> Log[x] + Log[y], Log[x_^n_] :> n Log[x]}
```

Written on [Simplify expressions with Log](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22705/simplify-expressions-with-log) by RunnyKine. Extremely easy to understand and to explain to the students. However, I've finally encountered a difficulty:

This worked:

[image]

But this didn't:

[image]

I tried a number of different things, like using the Algebraic Manipulation Palette, highlighting the interior, but none worked.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to write a general rule that takes a base like this:

```
logbaserule = {Log[k_, x_] + Log[k_, y_] :> Log[k, x y], n_ Log[k_, x_] :> Log[k, x^n]};

revlogbaserule = {Log[k_, x_ y_] :> Log[k, x] + Log[k, y], Log[k_, x_^n_] :> n Log[k, x]};
```

Now you can apply to your question:

```
Log[2, x + Sqrt[x^2 - 1]] + Log[2, x - Sqrt[x^2 - 1]] //. logbaserule // Simplify
```

> 0

You can also use `FullSimplify` with a transformation function to go directly to the final result:

```
tf[x_] := x /. logbaserule

FullSimplify[Log[2, x + Sqrt[x^2 - 1]] + Log[2, x - Sqrt[x^2 - 1]], 
                 TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, tf}]
```

> 0

Comment: It is nice as the approach, but why the result is zero? Evaluation `Log[2, x + Sqrt[x^2 + 1]] + Log[2, x - Sqrt[x^2 + 1]]/.x->0` yields `(I \[Pi])/Log[2]`, rather than zero.

Comment: No, I substituted `x->0` above. I mean that the approach is, in principle good, but the answer is wrong. On my machine the application of logbaserule gave me a correct answer, but FullSimplify gave 0.

Comment: @AlexeiBoulbitch What do you get when you multiply `x + Sqrt[x^2 - 1]` by `x - Sqrt[x^2 - 1]` and `Simplify`? If you get `1`, then `Log` of `1` should be `0`

Comment: @RunnyKine Thanks for your response. This is quite helpful for my students.

Comment: @David. You're welcome, glad I could help.