# Simplification of logarithms

Tags: simplifying-expressions

From the [Wolfram functions](http://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Log/16/04/01/) web site it is known that

> $$\log(z_1)+\log(z_2)=\log(z_1z_2),\text{ for $z_1+z_2>0$}$$

In an answer to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/22705/simplify-expressions-with-log/22746#22746) question Alexei Boulbitch wrote a useful function `collectLog`. However, this function does not impose conditions on the `Log`-arguments.

Therefore, my question is, how should `collectLog` look like, so that it can be used in

```
FullSimplify[Log[a] + Log[b], 
 TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, collectLog}, 
 Assumptions -> a + b > 0]
```

providing the desired simplification **only when the condition is met**.

### Addendum

In trying to create a minimal example I simplify the problem too much. In fact, the main motivation is to combine two `Log`-functions together when it can be inferred from the given [assumptions](/questions/tagged/assumptions) that the sum of arguments is positive. In many cases the solution of Carl Woll already works fine. For instance here

```
Assuming[a∈Reals,FullSimplify[Log[1-Sin[a]]+Log[1+Sin[a]],
                  TransformationFunctions->{Automatic,LogContract}]]
(* Log[Cos[a]^2] *)
```

The product of `1-Sin[a]` and `1+Sin[a]` is equal to `Cos[a]^2`, which *is* positive for $x\in\mathbb{R}$, thus, endorsing the simplification.
However, there are many exceptions that I would like to be addressed too. Below are **two simple examples** where the `LogContract` fails.

- **Identity 1**

> $$\log(\mathrm{sign}\,x)+\log(x)=\log(x\,\mathrm{sign}\,x)=\log{\!|x|},\text{ for $x\in\mathbb{R}$.}$$

```
Assuming[a∈Reals,FullSimplify[Log[Sign[a]]+Log[a],
                  TransformationFunctions->{Automatic,LogContract}]]
(* Log[a]+Log[Sign[a]] *)
```

**The expected result is** `Log[Abs[a]]`.

- **Identity 2**

> $$\log(1-\cos2x)-\log(1+\cos2x)=\log\!\left(\frac{1-\cos2x}{1+\cos2x}\right)=\log\!\left(\tan^2\!x\right),\text{ for $x\in\mathbb{R}$.}$$

```
Assuming[a∈Reals,FullSimplify[Log[1-Cos[2 x]]-Log[1+Cos[2 x]],
                  TransformationFunctions->{Automatic,LogContract}]]
(*-Log[Cos[x]^2]+Log[Sin[x]^2]*)
```

**The expected result is** `Log[Tan[x]^2]`.

### Comment

Many expressions of this kind result from the [integration](/questions/tagged/integration) and not artificially constructed just to make the function fail. At the moment it is a rather laborious process to bring the expressions to a human-readable form.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One idea is to make use of [`PowerExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PowerExpand) with its [`Assumptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assumptions) option. For example, consider:

```
PowerExpand[Log[a b], Assumptions->a+b>0]
```

> Log[a] + Log[b]

Of course, [`PowerExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PowerExpand) is going the wrong direction! However, we can go in the right direction by using something like:

```
Log[a] + Log[b] /. Log[x_] + Log[y_] :> Log[x y] + 
    PowerExpand[Log[x] + Log[y] - Log[x y], Assumptions->x+y>0]
```

> Log[a b]

The function `LogContract`, defined below, does this more generally, accounting for sums that are not pure sums of [`Log`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Log) expressions (e.g., `Log[x] + 3 Log[y] + 4`):

```
Options[LogContract] = {Assumptions :> $Assumptions};

LogContract[e_, OptionsPattern[]] := Block[{$Assumptions = OptionValue[Assumptions]},
    e /. {l_Log :> l, Plus->iplus}
]

iplus[a__]:=Module[{logArgs, nonlogs, sum, product},
    {logArgs, nonlogs} = Transpose @ Replace[{a},
        {
        z_. Log[v_] :> {v^z, Simplify @ PowerExpand[z Log[v]-Log[v^z], Assumptions->True]},
        o_ :> {1, o}
        },
        {1}
    ];
    sum = Total[Log[logArgs]];
    product = Log[Times @@ logArgs];
    Simplify[
        product + PowerExpand[sum - product, Assumptions->$Assumptions] + Total[nonlogs]
    ]
]
```

Your example:

```
LogContract[Log[a] + Log[b], Assumptions -> a + b > 0]
```

> Log[a b]

A slightly more complicated example:

```
LogContract[Log[x] + 3 Log[y] + 4, Assumptions -> x>0 && y<0]
```

> 4 + 2 I π + Log[x y^3]

Check that the above transformation is correct for a random example:

```
SeedRandom[1];
rules = Thread @ Rule[{x, y}, {RandomReal[1], -RandomReal[1]}];

Log[x] + 3 Log[y] + 4 /. rules
4 + 2 I π + Log[x y^3] /. rules
```

> -2.785 + 9.42478 I

> -2.785 + 9.42478 I

**Addendum**

If you want to make use of LogContract with assumptions inside of [`FullSimplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullSimplify), you will need to use [`Assuming`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assuming) instead of giving [`FullSimplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullSimplify) the [`Assumptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assumptions) option. This is because [`FullSimplify`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullSimplify) does not change [`$Assumptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$Assumptions) while performing simplifications. So:

```
Assuming[
    a + b > 0,
    FullSimplify[Log[a] + Log[b], TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, LogContract}]
]
```

> Log[a b]

**Update on OP comments (after 2 1/2 years!)**

Identity 1 is only true for positive real parts, for example:

```
Log[-1] + Log[-2]
```

> 2 I Pi + Log[2]

is a counter example. So, you need a better assumption:

```
LogContract[Log[Sign[x]] + Log[x], Assumptions -> Re[x]>0]
```

> Log[x Sign[x]]

Identity 2 manifested a bug in my code, which I just fixed (by avoiding messing up the insides of Log objects):

```
LogContract[Log[1 - Cos[2 x]] - Log[1 + Cos[2 x]], Assumptions -> x ∈ Reals]
```

> Log[Tan[x]^2]

Comment: Nice solution! Indeed it works in many cases, but also fails sometimes. I've amended my post after realizing that I oversimplified the original problem in trying to construct a minimal example. Could you please have a look at the two examples that still make a problem. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

For positive values I just use a simple rule:

```
logsimp := {n_ Log[x_] -> Log[x^n], Log[x_] - Log[y_] -> Log[x/y], 
  Log[x_] + Log[y_] -> Log[x y], Log[1/x_] -> -Log[x]}

Log[x] + 3 Log[y] //. logsimp
(*Log[x y^3]*)

Log[x] - Log[y]/3 //. logsimp
(*Log[x/y^(1/3)]*)
```

You can wrap this rule about any part of your expression if you don't want to simplify all of it.