# Why MMA refuses to simplify the following simple expression?

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I have the following simple expression

```
Exp[(Log[1 + x]^2 - Log[x]^2)/Log[1 + 1/x]] - x^2
```

that can be shown to simplify to `x` for positive `x` (and same for $x < -1$ if principal branch of `log` is taken, $\log (x) = i \pi + \log (-x)$). However, none of the following

```
Simplify[Exp[(Log[1 + x]^2 - Log[x]^2)/Log[1 + 1/x]] - x^2]
FullSimplify[Exp[(Log[1 + x]^2 - Log[x]^2)/Log[1 + 1/x]] - x^2]
Simplify[Exp[(Log[1 + x]^2 - Log[x]^2)/Log[1 + 1/x]] - x^2, 
 Assumptions -> {x > 0}]
FullSimplify[Exp[(Log[1 + x]^2 - Log[x]^2)/Log[1 + 1/x]] - x^2, 
 Assumptions -> {x > 0}]
```

finds this simplification. Why is that? To show that the expression simplifies accordingly, use $a^2 - b^2 = (a+b)(a-b)$ formula inside the exponential and in the denominator $\log (1+1/x) = \log (1+x) - \log(x)$. Some stuff cancels out and you'll be left with $\exp \log (x+x^2) - x^2 = x$. I have no clue why MMA didn't choose to go down this route, I assumed that the common formulas like $a^n - b^n$ are known to it. I tried `Simplify[Log[1 + 1/x] + Log[x], Assumptions -> {x > 0}]` and it correctly returned `log[1+x]`, so this might not be the issue here.

This specific expression came up in some wider context, I frequently use MMA to simplify expressions after integration to get some nicer form and was surprised that this couldn't be simplified.

Comment: I tried with `Maple` and it can do it.

Comment: While it isn't `Simplify` at least `Reduce[Exp[(Log[1+x]^2-Log[x]^2)/Log[1+1/x]]-x^2==x && x>0,x]` returns `0<x<Infinity` but it says it cannot accomplish this when given `x < -1` which I am guessing is because of the principal branch issue.

Comment: Somewhat relevant https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/207506/9469

Comment: Marius, I'm not familiar with Maple, sorry :) @Bill this is reassuring, there is a way to verify it after all! The region $x < -1$ is not that important to me, in my application $x$ was positive anyway, I mentioned it only for completeness. However, I'm more interested in applications that yield the result, rather than verifying something I already worked out manually outside of MMA...

Comment: @yarchik. `LogContract[Exp[(Log[1 + x]^2 - Log[x]^2)/Log[1 + 1/x]], 
 Assumptions -> x > 0]` Fail ?

Comment: How about `Expand[Exp[
   FullSimplify[
    FunctionExpand[(Log[1 + x]^2 - Log[x]^2)/Log[1 + 1/x], 
     Assumptions -> x > 0], Assumptions -> x > 0]] - x^2]` which results in `x` in version 12.2?

Comment: `PowerExpand[Factor[#]]&//@ex` seems to work, where `ex` is your expression.

Comment: @Simon Woods very clever! but you can also put it that way `PowerExpand@*Factor //@ f`

Answer (score 5):

Let `y` be your expression. Here is the way to establish the desired fact:

```
a = Assuming[x > 0, D[y, x] // FullSimplify]
(* 1 *)
b = Limit[y, x -> 1]
(* 1 *)
Y = DSolveValue[{z'[x] == a, z[1] == b}, z, x];
Y[x]
(* x *)
```

Of course, it is an indirect albeit mathematically rigorous way.

**Explanation**
Assume we would like to simplify a function $y(x)$.The function $y(x)$ is such that direct simplification is not possible. However, the derivative of it is better handled by MA. Denote
$$
a(x)=y'(x)\\
b=y(p).
$$
Then the *simplified* function can be obtained by solving the ODE
$$
\frac{\mathrm{d}y(x)}{\mathrm{d}x}=a(x),\quad y(p)=b.
$$

**Organizing into a function**

```
AltSimplify[f_, x_, p_, assump_] := 
Assuming[assump, 
  DSolveValue[{z'[x] == FullSimplify[D[f, x]], z[p] == Limit[f, x -> p]}, z, x][x]]

AltSimplify[y, x, 1, x > 0]
(* x *)
```

Comment: I am sorry, I just fail to see how this is related to my question at all :O What differential equation are you solving, and why? Care to explain?

Comment: @user16320 See edits

Answer (score 5):

Change the complexity function so that it discourages log powers and log sums, which in turn converts $\log(a)+\log(b)$ into $\log(a b)$ and $\log(a)^2-\log(b)^2$ into $(\log(a)+\log(b))(\log(a)-\log(b))$:

```
FullSimplify[E^((-Log[x]^2 + Log[1 + x]^2)/Log[1 + 1/x]) - x^2,
  Assumptions -> x > 0,
  ComplexityFunction -> Function[LeafCount[#] + 
    100 Count[#, Log[_] + Log[_], {0, Infinity}] + 
    100 Count[#, Log[_]^_, {0, Infinity}]
  ]
]
(* x *)
```

Note that it works with the assumption $x<-1$ as well.

Comment: I'm not familiar with LeafCount, but this sounds promising! Thanks! (also, I just realized that (* x *) looks like a cute face)

Comment: Very nice solution. By the way, you can post it as an answer to my old unanswered question https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/207506/9469.

Answer (score 4):

As stated in the documentation for [`Simplify`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify.html):

> Simplify tries expanding, factoring, and doing many other transformations on expressions, keeping track of the simplest form obtained.

For some simplifications, such as yours, the required transformations actually *increase* complexity (as measured by Mathematica) before the cancellations can occur. This can be seen by using the default complexity function `` Simplify`SimplifyCount ``:

```
Simplify`SimplifyCount[Log[1 + 1/x]]
(* 7 *)

Simplify`SimplifyCount[Log[1 + x] - Log[x]]
(* 10 *)

Simplify`SimplifyCount[Log[1 + x]^2 - Log[x]^2]
(* 14 *)

Simplify`SimplifyCount[(Log[1 + x] - Log[x])(Log[1 + x] + Log[x])]
(* 18 *)
```

I don't believe the details of `Simplify`'s algorithm are publically documented, but it appears likely that it abandons these transformations due to the increasing complexity, before getting to the point where the simplification can occur.

For more discussion on simplification look at some of the highly rated answers with the [simplifying-expressions](/questions/tagged/simplifying-expressions) tag:
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bsimplifying-expressions%5d%20is%3aa

Answer (score 3):

```
expr = Exp[(Log[1 + x]^2 - Log[x]^2)/Log[1 + 1/x]] - x^2;

FullSimplify[expr, x > 0, ComplexityFunction -> StringLength@*ToString]

FullSimplify[expr, 
  TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, PowerExpand[#, Assumptions -> x > 0] &}]
```

> x
> x

Comment: Definitely a very neat solution! Am I understanding it right, ComplexityFunction sets the criterion for what the Simplify should aim as a "good simplified expression"? From Simon's answer it seems that MMA gives up too quickly before even having a chance to discover that "x" is the simplification, because it first has to expand the expression before it shrinks to x ("it has to get worse before it gets better"). However, with the ComplexityFunction you provided it simplified to x. By the way, what is the last command for? For me, Simplify with provided ComplexityFunction did the job already...