# How to use SuperLog by loading SMLE.m

Tags: simplifying-expressions, packages

I am researching a software reliability model that has many parameters that need to be estimated. I want to use a maximum likelihood estimator (MLE) to estimate those parameters.

After I searched this site for similar problems, I know that `SuperLog` in SMLE.m package is helpful for MLE. And I find the paper(http://www.tri.org.au/RoseSmithD.pdf), this paper provided code of SMLE.m in Appendix B. I try to copy code from Appendix B and follow instruction in the lower half of page 230, but I still can not get the expected result(See following image).

Can anyone help me? My research is suspended for this point.Thanks in advance.

**SMLE.m** which I copy from the paper:

```
(*:Name: SMLE *)
(*:Authors: Colin Rose and Murray D. Smith *)
(*:Version: Mathematica v3, or v4, or later required *)
(*:Legal: Copyright 1999 *)
(*:Summary: Symbolic Maximum Likelihood Estimation *)
BeginPackage["SMLE`"]
SuperLog::usage ="SuperLog[On] activates the enhanced Log operator, so that Log[Product[_ _]] objects get converted into sums of logs. SuperLog[Off] switches the enhancement off."
Begin["`Private`"]
SuperLog[Q_]:=Module[{erk, iii, nnn},
Product[iii,{iii,nnn}]; (* pre-load Product *)
Which[
Q === On,
Unprotect[Log]; Clear[Log];
Log[Product[x_, {k_, a_, b_}]]:=Log[Product[Times[erk, x], {k, a, b}]]/.erk ->1;
Log[Product[HoldPattern[Times[x__]], {k_, a_, b_}]]:=Simplify[Map[Sum[#, {k, a, b}]&, Plus@@Map[Expand[PowerExpand[Log[#]]]&,List[x]]]//.Sum[u_. w_, {kk_, aa_, bb_}] :>u  Sum[w,{kk, aa, bb}] /; FreeQ[u, kk]==True];
Protect[Log]; Print["SuperLog is now On."],
Q === Off,
Unprotect[Log]; Clear[Log]; Protect[Log]; Print["SuperLog is now Off."],
True,
Print["Carumbah! Please use SuperLog[On] or SuperLog[Off]."]
]]
End[]
Protect[ SuperLog ];
```

Link of SMLE.m : https://www.dropbox.com/s/e8w8yc15z8t3rw1/SMLE.m

[image: superlog]

Comment: Please, provide code in `InputForm` rather than $\LaTeX{}$ or images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is: What do you expect when you set `n=10`? The computation in the paper is done with unknown `n` and yields a general simplification. You can easily reproduce this when you `Clear[n]`. Here is the complete code

```
(*:Name:SMLE*)
(*:Authors:Colin Rose and Murray D.Smith*)
(*:Version:Mathematica v3,or v4,or later required*)
(*:Legal:Copyright 1999*)
(*:Summary:Symbolic Maximum Likelihood Estimation*)
BeginPackage["SMLE`"];
SuperLog::usage = "SuperLog[On] activates the enhanced Log operator, \
so that Log[Product[_ _]] objects get converted into sums of logs. \
SuperLog[Off] switches the enhancement off."
Begin["`Private`"];
SuperLog[Q_] := 
 Module[{erk, iii, nnn}, Product[iii, {iii, nnn}];(*pre-load Product*)
  Which[Q === On, Unprotect[Log]; Clear[Log];
   Log[Product[x_, {k_, a_, b_}]] := 
    Log[Product[Times[erk, x], {k, a, b}]] /. erk -> 1;
   Log[Product[HoldPattern[Times[x__]], {k_, a_, b_}]] := 
    Simplify[
     Map[Sum[#, {k, a, b}] &, 
       Plus @@ Map[Expand[PowerExpand[Log[#]]] &, List[x]]] //. 
      Sum[u_. w_, {kk_, aa_, bb_}] :> 
       u Sum[w, {kk, aa, bb}] /; FreeQ[u, kk] == True];
   Protect[Log]; Print["SuperLog is now On."], Q === Off, 
   Unprotect[Log]; Clear[Log]; Protect[Log]; 
   Print["SuperLog is now Off."], True, 
   Print["Carumbah! Please use SuperLog[On] or SuperLog[Off]."]]]
End[];
Protect[SuperLog];
EndPackage[];

L = Product[Exp[-\[Theta]]*\[Theta]^y[i]/y[i]!, {i, 1, n}];
SuperLog[On];
Log[L]
```

This gives the expected result

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

Use `Log` directly after loading SMLE and not SMLE`Log, like this:

```
Get["SMLE.m"]
m = Product[Exp[-theta] theta^y[i]/Factorial[y[i]], {i, 1, n}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
SuperLog[On]
Logm = Log[m]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you use the SMLE`Log, it does not work: (restart KERNEL fresh):

```
Get["SMLE.m"]
m = Product[Exp[-theta] theta^y[i]/Factorial[y[i]], {i, 1, n}]
SuperLog[On]
logm = SMLE`Log[m]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The reason is that the package does not actually define a `Log` function in SMLE context. What it does is modify the system `Log` function itself (in System context).

Hence, all what you have to do, is simply use `Log` and not SMLE`Log, as there is no such function in SMLE context.